# Is there a way to temporarily change the display refresh rate so that after rebooting it doesn't stay the same?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

I am using a old monitor, it's a 1920x1200 resolution and It supports overclocking to 75Hz.

Problem is, if I set it to 75Hz and restart the computer, Windows will boot into a black screen and I have to DDU the driver in safe mode and reinstall to get the image working again..

I will be replacing the monitor in a couple of months and so I'm staying with this one.

Another thing is, I'm only able to set 75Hz while the Windows booted with 60Hz or below that, If I were to set say 61Hz and then reboot, same problem, the screen would be entirely black (out of range)

TLDR;

I need a software utility that I can use through command prompt to change the refresh rate temporarily that does not affect the registry settings.

Comment: @Tetsujin I use interpolation software and convert the video to "artificial" frames.

Comment: "artificial" doesn't give the whole plot, I'm afraid. Interpolation vs doubling is a **massive** difference, computationally & aesthetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The utility
[NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
can do this using the
[setdisplay command](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setdisplay.html).

Its full syntax is:

```
nircmd setdisplay {monitor:index/name} [width] [height] [color bits] {refresh rate} {-updatereg} {-allusers}
```

The command would be something like:

```
 nircmd setdisplay 1024 768 24 75
```

You may store the command in a `.bat` file for quicker action.
You may also copy the `.bat` file to the current user's Startup folder at

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

This shouldn't cause Windows to boot into a black screen, but just in case
verify before copying the file that you can boot into Safe mode when the computer
is turned-off.

Comment: I like the command syntax and yes, I was thinking to put that inside the startup. My question is does this work on Windows 10? I tried the command and it just shows loading cursor and nothing happens. Running 1909 version here.

Comment: Use the 64-bit variant if this is your case. Nircmd works for me, everything works except the `setdisplay` sub-command that does nothing. If it still hangs for you, I'll try to find another utility.

Comment: Tried both versions and it doesn't work, I suspect this is due to the way Windows 10 handles resolutions in registry, I think.

Comment: Try also [ChangeScreenResolution.exe](http://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/) with the command `ChangeScreenResolution.exe /f=75`.  This might need to run as Admin (did you try nircmd as Admin?).

Comment: I run my entire Windows with full admin privileges. I got the nircmd working on Windows 10 by setting the compatibility layer to Windows 7 =)

It works like a charm! Thanks a lot :D